# Do not allow internet connection for users that have set a proxy in their browser

Tags: proxy, content-filter, dansguardian, coovachilli

I installed `dansguardian` in my `Linux` server. Everything works well except one thing: if a user sets a different proxy (outside my LAN) in his browser, he'll be able to bypass `dansguardian`. Can anybody help me on how to prevent this?

**EDIT**: I have on my server an access controller - `ChilliSpot` - that listens to all requests did on port 80. And that controller redirects all requests did to it towards `dansguardian`. So, I think that should be enough, but it isn't. Any thoughts on what should I do more.

**N.B.** I'm more like a 'Linux' newbie (even if I'm not just a newbie to 'Linux') than like a `Linux` guru.

Comment: Do you allow outbound connections from your network ? You shouldn't if you want to enforce using the content filter.

Comment: As mentioned below, you should block connections from your LAN to the WAN. `Chillispot` will not deny these connections it just acts as an access control, but you should make sure (using IPTABLES) that direct connections from inside your network to the internet are not allowed.

Comment: @drcelus You're right, but if you consider that I set `ChilliSpot` to proxy all traffic to `dansguardian` (from `chilli.conf`), then I consider that direct connections to internet are not allowed. I think that I have a hole in my judgment, but where is it?

Comment: Just try to telnet to the outside from one of your clients, if it succeeds, then you should check your firewall. Try port 8080, it is widely used by proxies.

Comment: @drcelus I resolved it. There was a rule in my firewall in additon to `Chilli`'s rules. I only removed it and now everithing works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup your firewall to block ports 80 and 443 so he is forced to use your proxy to get to the internet

Comment: While that is a good starting point there are plenty of proxies running on other ports, specifically to get around such restrictions.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps my answer should be to block all outbound traffic

Comment: @Lock see my edit

Comment: @Lock yes, drop all TCP/UDP connections except for the proxy server.